# Crash app when recording in background and get incoming call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `SFSpeechRecognizer` work fine but when recording start in continues in background that time get incoming call app crash.

i am using this code

```
 AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [session setMode:AVAudioUnitTypeMixer error:&error];


AVAudioFormat *format = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];
    [inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];

    if (inputNode != nil)
    {
        [inputNode installTapOnBus: 0 bufferSize: 8192 format: format block: ^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buf, AVAudioTime *when)
         {
             [recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buf];
         }];
    }

 [audioEngine prepare];
```

error generate by xcode.

```
failed: '!pri' (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>)
 [central] 54:   ERROR:    [0x1af844c40] >avae> AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:883: SetOutputFormat: required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat)
```

Comment: show your code for `AVAudioSessionInterruption` Handling

Comment: show this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736809/avplayer-resuming-after-incoming-call

Answer (score 1):

You have to respond to app interruptions to prevent it from crashing.
For example: Incase of an interrupt like incoming call,

**After interruption starts**
Save state and context
Update user interface

**After interruption ends**
Restore state and context
Reactivate audio session if app appropriate
Update user interface

Please refer to link for further information [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html)

For example,

```
 AVAudioSession *session=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleInterruption:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:session];
- (void)handleInterruption:(NSNotification *)notification{}
```

Once you handle this particular usecase, you should be good to go.

Comment: good to see you. i am also try using notification but before get notification app crash.