# How to handle network interruption in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have using reachability to determine network change but once I determine I am trying to reload item but it is not working

```
// Check if the playback could keep up after a network interruption
private func checkNetworkInterruption() {
    guard
        let item = playerItem,
        !item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp,
        reachability?.connection != .unavailable else { return }

    self.player?.pause()

    // Wait 1 sec to recheck and make sure the reload is needed
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
        if !item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
            self.reloadItem()
        }
        self.isPlaying ? self.playSong() : self.player?.pause()
    }
}
```

`private func reloadItem() {
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
 }`

Comment: when i try to player.play() nothing happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVplayer resuming after incoming call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736809/avplayer-resuming-after-incoming-call)

Comment: nope this didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer can handle the network interrupts by itself, when network fails, the video is paused and keep in buffering status when network is stable, the video is resumed.

but if you need to handle the network interruption, you can try:

```
private func checkNetworkInterruption() {
    guard
        let item = playerItem,
        !item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp,
        reachability?.connection != .unavailable else { return }

    self.player?.pause()

    // Wait 1 sec to recheck and make sure the reload is needed
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
        if !item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
            //you can create a new AVItem here 
            player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        }
        self.isPlaying ? self.playSong() : self.player?.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...but I am doing the same in reload item function and using avplayer for playing audio not video

Comment: private func reloadItem() {
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    }